# Nice way to do this regex substitution

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a javascript function which takes a regex and some elements against which it matches the regex against the name attribute.

Let's say i'm passed this regex

```
/cmw_step_attributes\]\[\d*\]/
```

and a string that is structured like this

```
"foo[bar][]chicken[123][cmw_step_attributes][456][name]"
```

where all the numbers could vary, or be missing.  I want to match the regex against the string in order to swap out the 456 for another number (which will vary), eg 789.  So, i want to end up with

```
"foo[bar][]chicken[123][cmw_step_attributes][789][name]"
```

The regex will match the string, but i can't swap out the whole regex for 789 as that will wipe out the "[cmw_step_attributes][" bit.  There must be a clean and simple way to do this but i can't get my head round it.  Any ideas?

thanks, max

Answer (score 2):

Capture the first part and put it back into the string.

```
.replace(/(cmw_step_attributes\]\[)\d*/, '$1789');
// note I removed the closing ] from the end - quantifiers are greedy so all numbers are selected
// alternatively:
.replace(/cmw_step_attributes\]\[\d*\]/, 'cmw_step_attributes][789]')
```

Comment: Thanks @Kolink.  What's the deal with the `$1` there?

Comment: The `$1` is a reference to the captured subpattern, in this case `cmw_step_attributes\]\[`.

Answer (score 1):

Either literally rewrite part that must remain the same in replacement string, or place it inside capturing brackets and reference it in replace.

Answer (score 1):

See answer on: [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets).

> Regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job because you are dealing with nested structures, i.e. recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var str = 'foo[bar][]chicken[123][cmw_step_attributes][456][name]';
str.replace(/cmw_step_attributes\]\[\d*?\]/gi, 'cmw_step_attributes][XXX]');
```

Comment: That would work but how do i do it dynamically, ie if i can get passed through any regex to match against the string, and want to switch out the \d part?

Comment: @MaxWilliams so like any thing in replace of `cmw_step_attributes`?